# Recursive CTE Returns Value Outside of Range

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

While searching for a method to create date ranges I came across a problem with the following query:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DateTime = '2000-01-01 01:00';
DECLARE @EndDate DateTime = '2020-01-01 00:00';

with Dates as (
  select
  @StartDate fromDate
  UNION ALL
  (Select
     fromDate = dateadd(day, 1, @EndDate)
   from
     Dates
   where
     fromDate >= @StartDate AND
     fromDate < @EndDate ))

Select * from Dates
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

The following query returns two rows, one of which is outside of the range,

```
fromDate
-----------------------
2000-01-01 01:00:00.000
2020-01-02 00:00:00.000
```

I am aware that there is a way to fix this issue by changing the second half of the query to be different, for example:

```
Select * from Dates Where fromDate <= @EndDate
```

I have the following questions:

- what is wrong with the query as is?
- Why is it that this query returns two values, one of which lies outside the range provided?

This is using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: What are you really trying to accomplish here? A recursive cte seems like the wrong tool for the job based on the query posted.

Comment: The query posted is only part of what the full query does. The full query depends on two conditions, Daily and Monthly. If Daily is true, the recursive CTE creates a result with days per row. If Monthly is true, the result is in increasing months per row. Otherwise, the result should be one row, the StartDate, @SeanLange

Comment: I see. I would suggest using a tally table instead of a recursive cte. Essentially you are using a recursive cte to generate a series of incrementing numbers. This is one of those weird things where it seems like a cool set based way to do this but it is really still basically a row by row thing behind the scenes. Jeff Moden wrote about this [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/74118/)

Comment: If you want to read more about a tally or numbers table and how you can use them check out Jeff's [article here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/)

Comment: Jeff Moden is most definitely someone you should read. And I am still of the opinion that every database should have at least a Tally Table and a Calendar Table. Those are both _IMMENSELY_ useful.

Comment: And not related to the question, but also keep in mind that SQL Server 2008 and 2008 R2 will hit End of Support in July 2019.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your `Recursive CTE` add one day from `fromDate`

```
Select
     fromDate = dateadd(day, 1, @EndDate)
```

but your condition filter `fromDate`

```
where
     fromDate >= @StartDate AND
     fromDate < @EndDate ))
```

---

If you want to do make calendar table by `Recursive  CTE`.

you can try this.

```
with Dates as (
  select @StartDate fromDate,@EndDate endDate
  UNION ALL
  Select
     fromDate = dateadd(day, 1, fromDate),endDate
   from
     Dates
   where
      dateadd(day, 1, fromDate) <= @EndDate 
)
Select * from Dates
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer for #1 / #2: You are selecting DATEADD(day, 1, @endDate) -- which, by definition, is 1 day 'over' your date range.

The real answer:  To get the result you want, change:

```
(Select
    fromDate = dateadd(day, 1, @EndDate)
```

To:

```
(Select
    fromDate = dateadd(day, 1, fromDate)
```